# Paging Event of GridView With Caching Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I displaying the Gridview data form cache object.When i click on the pagenumber it shows blank webpage. how to handle the paging with caching object .

Do i need to check the same condition in paging event

```
 DataTable GetByCahe =(DataTable) Cache["DataStore"];
            if (GetByCahe != null)
            {
                ManageRegGrid.DataSource = GetByCahe;
                ManageRegGrid.DataBind();
            }
            else
            load From the database
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need same checking and rebinding if the cached data is not available.